# prove $\omega (n)\ll\frac{\log(n)}{\log(\log(n))}$ where $\omega (n)$ is the number of distinct prime with out multiplicity that divide $n$.

Tags: number-theory

prove $$\omega (n)\ll\frac{\log(n)}{\log(\log(n))}$$ where $\omega (n)$ is the number of distinct prime with out multiplicity that divide $n$, i.e. $$\omega (n)=\sum_{p\mid n}1.$$

**Solution**

Let $N=\prod_{p\leq t}p$ where $t$ is the largest one s.t. $N\leq n$. So $$\omega (n)\leq \omega (N)\leq \pi(t).$$
I know that $\log(N)\gg t$ and $\pi(t)\ll \frac{t}{\log(t)}$. Therefore $\nu(n)\ll\frac{\log(N)}{\log(t)}.$ By maximality of $t$ we have that $$n\leq \prod_{p\leq t+1}p.$$
My teacher says that $\log(n)\ll t$, but I have problem with this estimation.

**Quest 1) To me $$\log(n)\ll t+1,$$
but is $t+1=\mathcal O(t)$ ?**

**Quest 2) Does $f(x)\sim x\implies f(x)=\mathcal O(x)$ ?**

**Quest 3) Suppose $\log(n)\ll t$. In what this implies that $\nu(n)\ll\frac{\log(n)}{\log(\log(n))}$ ?**

Comment: Do you understand the definitions of $\mathcal O$, $\sim$, and $\ll$?  The first two questions seem a bit odd if you do, and you might be well-served by asking those as a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed elementary (you don't need any estimation for $\pi(x)$).

As $x \to \infty$ $$x \sim  y \log y \qquad\implies \qquad y \sim \frac{x}{\log x}$$

Note that $$\omega(n) \ge N  \quad\implies\quad n \ge \prod_{p | n} p >  N!$$
Finally $\log N! = \sum_{m=1}^{N} \log m \sim N \log N$ so that
$$\omega(n) < \sup_{\log (N!) \le \log(n)} N \sim \sup_{N \log N \le \log(n)} N\sim \sup_{N \le \frac{\log(n)}{\log \log(n)}} N \sim \frac{\log(n)}{\log \log(n)} $$

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes.

2) Yes.

3) $$\log(n)\ll t\implies \log(\log(n))\ll\log(t)\implies \frac{1}{\log(t)}\ll \frac{1}{\log(\log(n))}$$

and thus $$\frac{\log(N)}{\log(t)}\ll \frac{\log(N)}{\log(\log(n))}.$$
Since $x\longmapsto \log(x)$ is increasing, you have the result.